# AngularJS $cookieStore gets cleared auto

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic Framework app. Also, I am using `$cookieStore` to store some array data. My array data gets stored in the `$cookieStore` unless the route changes.

Whenever I go back to the previous page the cookies get cleared.

This is what I have tried:

```
$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
        id: 1,
        qty: 10,
        description: 'sample',
        cost: 99 
    }]
};

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        id: $stateParams.foodId,
        qty: $scope.count,
        description:  $scope.ar_name,
        cost: $scope.total
    });

    $cookieStore.put("invoices",$scope.invoice.items);
    console.log(  $cookieStore.get("invoices",$scope.invoices));
    //var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('invoices');
    $scope.lastVal = $cookieStore.get('invoices');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $cookieStore is deprecated. Have you tried using $cookies https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies?

Are you able to set the path? I think cookies by default are set only for the current page rather than a root domain level. That may be why you're only seeing them on the first page?

If you try and use $cookies with the $cookiesProvider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider and set the path to '/'

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just replace `$cookieStore` with `localStorage`. It plays nice with both Android and iPhone.

```
$cookieStore.set() -> window.localStorage.setItem()
$cookieStore.get() -> window.localStorage.getItem()
$cookieStore.remove() -> window.localStorage.removeItem()
```